# jQuery Validator#remote with ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: jquery, webforms

I'm trying to use the jQuery Validator plugin with WebForms.  Here's my jQuery code:

```
$("input[id$=FromZip]").rules('add', {
    required: true,
    postalCode: true,
    remote: {
            url: "shipping companies.aspx/ValidatePostalCode",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{'postalCodeToValidate': '" + $("input[id$=FromZip]").val() + "'}",
            dataFilter: function(data) { return (JSON.parse(data)).d; }
    },
    messages: {
        required: '"From" zip code is required.',
        postalCode: 'Invalid "From" zip code',
        remote: 'The "From" zip code was not found in the database.'
    }
});
```

The problem with this is that the `val()` always returns empty, so the value is always being flagged as false.  I tried wrapping it in a function call, like so:

```
remote: function() {
    var r = { 
        url: "shipping companies.aspx/ValidatePostalCode",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: "{'postalCodeToValidate': '" + $("input[id$=FromZip]").val() + "'}",
        dataFilter: function(data) { return (JSON.parse(data)).d; }
    }
}
```

Except now the WebMethod isn't being called at all and no Ajax request is being made, while before (without the `var r = {}` stuff) the call was being made but passing empty data instead of the value from the textbox.  I've been trying to figure this out for the better part of a day now.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So I seem to have solved it partially by creating a custom method instead of using remote, but now it's flagging the field as invalid even when the response I get back from the server is: {"d": "true"}.  Even hard-coding a value of "True" in the custom method still flags the field as invalid!

Comment: I was able to fix it by creating a variable, assigning that variable in the success method handler, and then checking for the value outside of the Ajax call.  Strange, and there's almost certainly a better way to handle it, but it's solved.

Comment: Same problem happened to me, I changed to use custom method instead of remote. One catch for this custom method is you may need to set your ajax call async: false otherwise validator will show always false. this is where i got the idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966209/jquery-custom-validators-do-not-validate-on-keystroke

Answer (score 0):

You can write your remote function like that

```
   remote: function() {
      var value = $('#FromZip').val();
      var r = {
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'postalCodeToValidate': value }),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'shipping companies.aspx/ValidatePostalCode',
            dataFilter: function(data) { return $.parseJSON(data).d; }
      };
      return r;
   }
```