# ASP.NET WebForms & jQuery Validate's remote method

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, jquery-validate

Can anyone please tell me how I can get an ASP.NET WebMethod to return correctly-formatted data for display by jQuery Validate? Here's my code:

### Client-side code

```
$('#txtUName').rules('add', {
    remote: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Register.aspx/ValidateUserNameOrEmail',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'data' : $('#txtUName').val(),
            'valUser' : true
        }),
        dataFilter: function(result) {
            return $.parseJSON(result).d;
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }
});
```

### Server-side code

```
[WebMethod]
public static object ValidateUserNameOrEmail(string data, bool valUser)
{
    var col = valUser ? "userName" : "email";
    var label = valUser ? "username" : "email address";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(dbConn))
    using (var comm = new SqlCommand("", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        comm.CommandText = "SELECT userId FROM [dbo]." +
            "[User] WHERE " + col + " = '" + data + "'";
        if (comm.ExecuteScalar() != null)
        {
            // Entered username or email already exists in the DB
            return "A user with that " + label + " already " +
                "exists. Please enter a unique " + label + ".";
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**tl;dr** - Should I just give up on the fact that this is **supposed** to just work, and use a custom remote message? This should work, since I can see that false is definitely returned from a later call to `element.valid()` when the username is already taken. But I'd really like to avoid having to specify a custom message if possible.

**EDIT:** Indeed the above solution works, so I'll use it for now, but please read on and suggest a better solution if you can!

Stepping through both pieces of code, I can see that everything gets called and returned wonderfully, but jQuery Validate just refuses to display the damn error!

According to the [official docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/):

> The response is evaluated as JSON and must be true for valid elements, and can be any false, undefined or null for invalid elements, using the default message; **or a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to display as the error message.**

So what am I doing wrong?? As you can clearly see above, I return true in the case of success or an appropriate error message string otherwise, just like the docs say I should (well kind-of; see below).

According to those docs and [Asp.Net WebForm JQuery remote Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445055/asp-net-webform-jquery-remote-validation), I should be returning a JSON object from the server, but I don't see how that would make a difference when I'm parsing it into JSON on the client, to no avail. I would try the solution suggested in Jeff Siver's comment, but I'm guessing that's for MVC, since the `Sys` namespace doesn't exist on my system.

Sherif Ahmed's answer to [jQuery Validator#remote with ASP.NET WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759594/jquery-validatorremote-with-asp-net-webforms) is almost functionally-identical to my code, yet I'm getting a completely different result!

I gave up on the suggested StackOverflow posts after these two...my situation seems to be very-slightly-yet-significantly different to them all.

**EDIT for @Sparky** - Hi and thanks for replying. The first post I linked to does indeed mention using the `JavaScriptSerializer` class to return data in the proper format, so my apologies for not seeing that earlier. However, that isn't the answer you linked to. The answer you linked to (and that I read) mentions some unknown `Json` class...as Melursus says there:

> Can you provide me an example of how I can return a JSON object because I didn't find this namespace. I didn't find the ActionResult namespace either. So, I don't understand how I can use the proposed solution.

I initially saw that and stopped reading, but your comment prompted me to do further research and find the  `JavaScriptSerializer` solution that may actually work. I'll give it a go and let you know :-)

Comment: Add an alert `dataFilter: function(result) {alert($.parse.JSON(result).d);
            return $.parseJSON(result).d;
        },`. Whet does it return? Also, in your aspx page, how does your form look like? Do you have any commented lines? I ask this because sometimes WebForms does not take comments into consideration, and maybe this is why your messages do not appear. Try removing all your commented lines, if you have.

Comment: @Cristina - Hi again! Thanks for replying. No, after yesterday's episode with erroneous comments I've learned not to **ever** use comments in ASP.NET LOL :P I tried your alert suggestion and it showed the error message as expected, so everything's working in jQuery and ASP.NET, but it's just the validate plugin that's not playing fair! Using a custom `messages:` rule seems to have fixed it, so that'll have to do for now.

Comment: You **must** JSON encode the string on the server before you return it, whether you think it matters or not.

Comment: `dataType` defaults to `JSON`, so you don't need it.  You also should not have a `dataFilter` option within your `remote`.  The `remote` method is already programmed to handle the incoming server response.

Comment: See the answer actual answer referenced from the other answer you linked:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1250143/594235

Comment: @Sparky - I've responded to almost everything you said with an edit to the OP, since comments are length-restricted. But I forgot to mention 3 things: 1. As I said to Cristina, adding a custom `messages` rule and the `dataFilter` works, so why is it so absolutely-necessary to JSON-encode on the server? 2. A lot of AJAX-related examples that I've seen on SO and elsewhere mention the `dataType` parameter, so I thought it was necessary, but thanks for teaching me otherwise :-) 3. The only reason I added `dataFilter` was to debug this issue, and as I just said it's needed for my custom solution.

Comment: The `remote` method of this plugin is only programmed to interpret a JSON response.  If you want to know why, then you'll have to [ask Jörn Zaefferer, the developer](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation).

Comment: You directly linked to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1445100/594235), which clearly states:  *"...your page method still has to return a JSON object.   So the solution in that post should work fine"* ~  And _"that post"_ is referring to the link in the question itself.  Scroll up and click the link in the question.   Then scroll down and look at its accepted answer.   I know it's confusing, which is why we frown upon content that depends on clicking other questions that depend on clicking other questions, etc.

Comment: Please don't discuss and/or complain/rant about SO in the question, answer or comments.  That's why we have [the SO meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).  Please use it instead.  Thanks.

Comment: LOL I don't think I need to bother Jörn about it; I've found a solution that works well-enough for me. But I get your point; asking you about it is pointless, so I apologise for that. I wasn't aware of the meta site; thanks for letting me know. I'll post what I said there and hopefully it'll get noticed. As for your redirection back to the same post again, I saw that 3 hours ago, but what is the `Json` class? In which namespace is it defined? I couldn't find it, nor could Melursus if I understand his comment properly.

Comment: I can only speak to the Validate plugin as I am **very** familiar with how to use it.  Unfortunately, I know little about ASP, which is why I have not posted an answer for you here. Surely, there is some ASP documentation that shows you how to convert a string to JSON?  Not sure if this will work:    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yeah that `JavaScriptSerializer` class seems to be the best-possible solution, as I said before. I still haven't tried it since `dataFilter` and `messages` allows me to simply return `true` or `false`. But in the interest of being **really** standards- and conventions-compliant, I'll give it a go tomorrow. Thanks again for all your time devoted to this post :D

Comment: I don't think you'll want to keep the `dataFilter` option.  As I stated, the `remote` method already knows how to handle the server response.

Comment: @Sparky Agreed, if I can get rid of `dataFilter` and `messages` I should, but `JavaScriptSerializer` isn't the answer. I suspect that the damn d parameter that ASP.NET wraps AJAX responses in is getting in the way...see [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588589/why-do-asp-net-json-web-services-return-the-result-in-d#6588603) for further explanation.